# increasing upload speed (multipart POST)

Tags: networking, file-upload, mobile, performance

I have a phone application and I use multipart POST to upload multiple files. Is there a way to increase the uploading speed ? e.g. can multithreading the upload process increase the upload speed, is there any other strategy? can anyone refer me to any networks research regarding this area?

If I switch from multipart POST to opening a direct socket stream with server is that going to increase the upload speed ?

How about if I upload chunk of bytes one at at time will that increase upload speed? I also face issues host not resolved or pipe broken. It probably has to do with the fact that a video is 14mb in size and being attempted to upload in just one go.

Answer (score 2):

My gut reaction would be to say that on a phone application the limiting factor is going to be your upload bandwidth.

I would expect a single thread of execution will quite happily consume all of the available bandwidth making multi-threading pointless.

You may be better off looking at ways of compressing the data before you transmit it to reduce the time taken to do the upload?  Also, if you're talking about a large number of files, there may be a slightly reduced overhead if you were to compress them into a single file and upload that.